# how to move an object to the center of the stage in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, move

I have an Object on stage, and on click I would like it to move to the center of the stage.
I know that I am supposed to use:

```
<s:move />
```

But I just don't know how!

Comment: Which component is the parent component of this object? Is it just an empty flex-application or do you have another objects like Group or BorderContainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using attribute x... i used mouseX and everything worked as expected!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample app that does what you want, you can play around with the properties of the move effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:Move id="moveEffect"></s:Move>
    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:BorderContainer id="box">

    </s:BorderContainer>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        private function init():void 
        {
            box.setStyle("backgroundColor", "#ff0000");
            box.width = 200;
            box.height = 200;
            box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

            moveEffect.xTo = (width-box.width)/ 2;
            moveEffect.yTo = (height-box.height) / 2;
        }

        private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            moveEffect.play([box]);
        }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Hope that helps.